# Glass look for MDI windows under Vista

Tags: c#, windows-vista, mdi, aero, aero-glass

I am developing a winforms MDI application in C# in VS 2008.
I have noticed that the MDI forms don't have the glass look under Vista.

Is this by design?
Is there a simple way to get the glass look for these windows?

Answer (score 5):

By default glass is not enabled on WinForms (or for that matter WPF applications).  The only way to enable glass is to PInvoke into native API's.  This channel9 site does a tutorial for a great utility that makse it trivial to add Glass effects to your controls.

http://channel9.msdn.com/playground/Sandbox/201158/

Answer (score 2):

Nope, Glass is not available for MDI children.